# Minimum number of replications for certain confidence interval Par(3) distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have some trouble solving the following question:

Given are $M$ replications of $Par(3)$ distributed stochasts $X_1,X_2,...,X_i$. Known is that $Var(x_i)=3/4$. Now I have to determine, using Chebyshev's inequality, the minimum value of $M$ for which the chance on an error less than 0.05 is 0.9. So I need the $M$ in the following equation: $P(\mu-0.05\le X_M \le \mu +0.05)=0.9$. I can't figure out how all these things are related and how to solve this without knowing the expected value itself. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, Chebychev's inequality states: $P(|X-\mu|\geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$

Also, as written your statement does not make sense, as $P(\mu-0.05\le X_M \le \mu +0.05)=0.9$ is a feature of the distribution, not the sample size. However, if you meant $\bar X_M$ then this makes sense. This can be rewritten as $P(|\bar X_M-\mu|\leq 0.05)=0.9$. Now, Chebyshevs inequality does not give you an *exact* error bound, only an upper bound. Therefore, you cannot use Chebyshev's inequality to answer your question as stated. However, you *can* answer the related question: $P(|\bar X_M-\mu|\leq 0.05)\geq0.9$

Rearranging the senses of the inequality we get:

$P(|\bar X_M-\mu|\leq 0.05)=1-P(|\bar X_M-\mu|> 0.05)\geq1-\frac{\sigma_{x_i}^2}{0.05^2M}$ since the variance of the sample average decreses as $\frac{1}{M}$. Now select M using your known variance to get the required sample size.